# T-sql: Case show date or convert date to nvarchar

Tags: t-sql, type-conversion

I want to use a case statement where my logic determines a date. If the value returned is a null value I instead want to display 'none' instead of a null value.

See code below.

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, vso.pod_ata, ISNULL(cncr.cntr_date3, GETUTCDATE())) - 14 > 0 THEN vso.pod_ata + 14
ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), 'none')
END AS 'start_dem',
```

SQL SERVER was complaining about conversion so I tried converting it to nvarchar but thats not working. Does anyone know a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL, to my knowledge, does not allow mixed datatypes in the same column. Convert the `vso.pod_ata + 14` to an `NVARCHAR` as well.

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, vso.pod_ata, ISNULL(cncr.cntr_date3, GETUTCDATE())) - 14 > 0 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), vso.pod_ata + 14)
ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), 'none')
END AS 'start_dem',
```

Comment: This works but when I do this I lose the date formatting. I want it so the date is in yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: @nickgowdy: [Pick the format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx "CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)") that suits you then, [truncate the string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx "SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)") afterwards if necessary.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because I used this code and added the date format code from @AndriyM comment. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 4):

You should convert the date, not the string.

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, vso.pod_ata, ISNULL(cncr.cntr_date3, GETUTCDATE())) > 14 THEN convert(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day, 14, vso.pod_ata), 120)  
ELSE 'none'
END AS 'start_dem',
```

Comment: Since our answers were very similar, I applied the changes from my answer to your answer to give the OP the format he requested. I then deleted my own answer and upvoted yours.